# **Question:** How many ways to make $m$ tasks done, given that there are $n$ people doing all tasks?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:** How many ways to make $m$ tasks done, given that there are $n$ people, each people is capable of doing from $0$ to $m$ tasks, many people can take over 1 tasks.

This can be express in a binary array size $n*m$

Beolow is one case.

**Examples:** $n=2, m=2$.

There are $9$ ways to make $m=2$ tasks done.

Let denote that $2$ people are $P1$ and $P2$, $2$ tasks are $T1$ and $T2$.

So, we can express $9$ cases in binary that make $T1; T2$ done

$0011$ means that $P1$ do nothing and $P2$ covers $2$ tasks.
Apart from this, we have $8$ other ways: $1001; 0110; 1100; 0111; 1011; 1110; 1101; 1111.$

There are $7$ cases that does not take into accounts as follows:

$0000;0001;0010;0100;1000;0101;1010.$

in the last two cases $0101; 1010$ just only task $T1$ or $T2$ done.

Your help is highly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please help me, thank you. Ngoc Le

Comment: See [Wikipedia on combinations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).  There are ${n \choose k}=\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ ways to choose $k$ items out of $n$.  If you want at least $k$, add up all the possible values.

Comment: Thanks Ross for your response. Yeah, I did this way but it is not exactly the answer. Because when we choose k items our of n items, in k items we do not know 0 or 1 in k items. As required k items must be 1. So your answer can be bigger than the expected result. Thank you Ross so much.

Comment: Thank you Jason for your edit my written problems. It is clear and explicit. I will improve my writing. Thanks

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a simple closed formula. But as Ross says, you have to add up the binomial coefficients: $$\sum_{j=k}^n{n \choose j}$$

Comment: Thanks @Théophile. I am sorry if I ask not clear question. But this is the not the answer. When choose k items. We do not care about 0 or 1. Yes, it is the formula that we need. But the all the k items must be 1. Then the answer may be different. Thanks

Comment: You need to make your question clear.  In the main question you are talking about bit strings of length $n$   There are $n \choose k$ ways to make such a string with $k\ 1$'s.  I don't understand what you mean my answer can be bigger than the desired result.

Comment: I am sorry if I raise the wrong question. I will edit my problem again to make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: I editted my real problem about $n$ people doing $m$ tasks. I am sorry if the question before makes you confused. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The expression _'how many ways'_ is a bit vague. You are not interested in scheduling the work, in work per time balancing, in sharing tasks, in queueing them etc., are you? You are just asking how many assignments of $n$ workers to $m$ tasks there are, which cover all tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [exclusion-inclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) has something to do here. You need all possible binary fillings of the $m\times n$ matrix, *minus* those which leave *any* task unhandled, *plus* those which leave *any two* tasks unhandles, *minus* those which leave *any three* tasks unhandled... and so on. Of course there are $m={m\choose 1}$ tasks which can be unhandled, or $m\choose 2$ pairs of tasks, or $m\choose 3$ triples of tasks...
Finally, your number is
$$2^{nm}-m\cdot2^{n(m-1)} + \tfrac{m(m-1)}2\cdot2^{n(m-2)}-\ldots\pm 1$$
$$= \sum_{i=0}^m (-1)^i{m\choose i}\cdot 2^{n(m-i)}$$
This, however, does not necessarily keep all workers involved - the sum covers also such configurations in which just one of $n$ people does all $m$ tasks.